# Assign variable from API call in Java

Tags: javascript, api

So... I'm trying to write a quick and dirty macro for some of my video endpoints, and while I can write Python and shell scripts.. Javascript isn't my strongest language.  ... and I'm dealing with an ignorance issue.

Goal: Implement a simple button that "mutes" and "unmutes" the video cameras on the system.. using a single button.  I can make this work using two buttons, but I really need it to work with just one (screen real-estate is limited).

I can query the codec to get the current state of video mute using an API, but how do I store the returned value from the initial API call as a variable I can then test against to flip things back and forth from Mute to unMute.

```
import xapi from 'xapi';

xapi.event.on('UserInterface Extensions Panel Clicked', (event) => {
  if (event.PanelId === "VideoMute") {
      xapi.Status.Video.Input.MainVideoMute
        .get()
        .then((MainVideoMute) => console.log("testing", MainVideoMute));
          if (MainVideoMute == "Off") {  //<= I need this to be an var for MainVideoMute 
          console.log("The Video Mute is off.");
          xapi.command("Video Input Mainvideo Mute"); //<= turns the camera off
        }
        else {
          xapi.command("Video Input Mainvideo unMute"); //<= turns the camera on
        }
    }});
```

Comment: Java or JS? They are *completely* different languages.

Comment: it's Javascript..

Comment: if you formatted your code you would see the `if` is after the `then`, not inside it. so `MainVideoMute` does not get set.. as you found out making a function to call in the then works, replacing the console log. you also dont need the vMuteCont function https://playcode.io/675860/

Answer (score 0):

So, after dorking around with this for more than an hour and being fairly pissed off about how nothing standard seemed to be working.. I took a guess at the variable not being exportable from extremely local confines.. and used a function to house the logic test and execution of the mute/unmute.  Works just fine now.

```
import xapi from 'xapi';
function vMuteCont(vMute){
  if (vMute == "Off") {
          console.log("The Video Mute is off.");
          xapi.command("Video Input Mainvideo Mute");
        }
        else {
          xapi.command("Video Input Mainvideo unMute");
        };
}
xapi.event.on('UserInterface Extensions Panel Clicked', (event) => {
  if (event.PanelId === "VideoMute") {
    xapi.status.get('Video Input MainVideoMute')
    .then(vMuteCont);
    }});
```